# tty says "-bash: flatpak: command not found" even through I don't have flatpak installed. It was uninstalled properly

Tags: linux, debian, tty, flatpak

I installed flatpak and when I didn't like it I uninstalled. Now whenever I do ctrl+alt+fx to go to tty I get this error

`-bash: flatpak: command not found`

[image: tty error]

I am using debian stable with kernel 4.19.0-16-amd64

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Flatpack` install some commands in the shell profile. If you remove:

```
/etc/profile.d/flatpak.sh
```

You should be ok.

Also note that to remove a package `apt-get remove ...` does not remove the configuration for a package, while `apt-get purge ...` removes both the package and the configuration (in this case `purge`  should have removed that file).

Answer (score -1):

As @Eduardo well said, running

```
# apt-get purge flatpak
```

will remove the files causing the problem.

```
# apt-get purge flatpak
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  flatpak*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 103 not upgraded.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 143676 files and directories currently installed.)
Purging configuration files for flatpak (1.2.5-0+deb10u4) ...
```

I prefer that command to removing files manually (file-names may change, but apt knows what it needs to know).

In my case, the package was also removed, but like you, the configuration file was left behind.

Comment: This seems to be just a confirmation of the existing answer.